# Apache ignite : Failed to parse Query on every request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, ignite

Hello everyone I currently have a problem with my spring data ignite. I cannot create a custom query. On the least of my requests, even the simplest, I get the following error:

```
Failed to parse query. Erreur de syntaxe dans linstruction SQL {0}
Syntax error in SQL statement {0}; SQL statement:
SELECT "ALLUSER"."USERPERSIST"._KEY, "ALLUSER"."USERPERSIST"._VAL FROM UserPersist WHERE email=:email AND IN userLogin (:userLogins) [42000-197]
```

my request looks like this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM UserPersist WHERE email=:email AND IN userLogin (:userLogins)")
public List<UserPersist> findUsers(@Param("userLogins") List<String> usersLogins,@Param("email") String email);
```

spring boot is currently in version 2.0.3.RELEASE
Apache ignite is in version 2.7.6 and i use the package ignite-spring-data_2.0

I also tried a simplified version without the IN, here is the complete trace

```
2020-05-05 11:00:52.877 ERROR 29036 --- [nio-8099-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Erreur de syntaxe dans linstruction SQL {0}
Syntax error in SQL statement {0}; SQL statement:
SELECT "ALLUSER"."USERPERSIST"._KEY, "ALLUSER"."USERPERSIST"._VAL FROM UserPersist WHERE email=:email [42000-197]] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Erreur de syntaxe dans linstruction SQL {0}
Syntax error in SQL statement {0}; SQL statement:
SELECT "ALLUSER"."USERPERSIST"._KEY, "ALLUSER"."USERPERSIST"._VAL FROM UserPersist WHERE email=:email [42000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:203)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:548)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSpecialType(Parser.java:4161)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:3646)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:3093)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2587)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2574)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2544)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2370)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2291)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2133)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1946)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1919)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:463)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:311)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:694)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.ConnectionManager.prepareStatementNoCache(ConnectionManager.java:363)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryParser.parseH2(QueryParser.java:345)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryParser.parse0(QueryParser.java:210)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:131)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.querySqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1060)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$3.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2406)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$3.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2402)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2919)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.lambda$querySqlFields$1(GridQueryProcessor.java:2422)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuerySafe(GridQueryProcessor.java:2460)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2396)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySql(GridQueryProcessor.java:2555)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:802)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:412)
    at org.apache.ignite.springdata20.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery.execute(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.findUsers(Unknown Source)
    at com.assurfleet.restfull.implementation.serviceUser.ServiceCoreUser.findUsers(ServiceCoreUser.java:81)
    at com.assurfleet.restfull.restfull.serviceDeclasin.user.UserService.findUser(UserService.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.assurfleet.restfull.util.auth.JWTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:26)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

someone has ever encountered this problem?

Comment: Seems like a version mismatch issue as you are using a higher version of jar which is compatible with 2.8 version of ignite whilst your Ignite Server is 2.7.6. Can you try with // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-spring-data
compile group: 'org.apache.ignite', name: 'ignite-spring-data', version: '2.7.6'

Comment: thank you for your response, unfortunately it seems that this is not the problem. I always get the same answer.

Comment: Can you just change that query to just take email for now and test again...that IN looks suspicious.

Comment: I get the same type of error, I will put the full trace higher

Comment: Can you try not writing custom query and try finder methods instead? findUserPersistByEmail

Comment: classic methods work, only custom queries are broke. I use them on other repository

Answer (score 0):

I don't think our Spring Data implementation (or Spring Data itself) supports `:placeholders`, making them sent to Ignite/H2 code verbatim and causing syntax errors. Try replacing them with `?`'s.